# Independence of Random Variables in measure theoretic sense

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

In preparation for my graduate school, I am studying probability theory myself but am confused about the independence of random variables and it has been weeks since I am stuck on this. Could you please all share your thoughts?

Definition of independence of events

[image]

So this says that two random variables are independent if the events  {X $ \in A$} and {Y$\in B$} are independent. But here this assumes that there is same probability measure "P" defined on domain space $\Omega$. Therefore, using P on these sets makes sense. How would this definition make sense when we want to show whether two Normal Random variables in R are independent? What should be the underlying ($\Omega$,$\wp$, P) in that case?
Moreover, doesn't each Normal RV generate a different probability measure on R with Borel Sigma-Algebra, then does this make sense to speak about independence when we have different measures?

Comment: Your first link gives a 404 error, and your second link is to a text-heavy image.  Please fix the first link, and copy the text of the second link into your question (images are not terribly searchable, eat up bandwidth, and are inaccessible to folk who access the site using screenreaders).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  The first link doesn't work.  Anyway, please type your questions instead of posting links where possible.  If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  tutorial.

Comment: These might be related to your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429178/why-can-two-random-variables-be-added-only-when-they-have-the-same-domain and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450215/how-to-interpret-sum-of-two-random-variables-that-cross-domains

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Joe
I am confused about the following question: How to prove the independence of any two normally distributed random variables in the measure-theoretic sense? Do we assume some standard probability measure on R as we assume standard sigma-algebra in the form of Borel sets?

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed.  It is a perfectly reasonable question based on a natural misunderstanding.

Comment: I do believe that it is often assumed, or even considered part of the definition of a real random variable, that the sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is the Borel algebra. But I am not sure what you mean by needing to assume the probability measure, when you state that the random variables are normally distributed. Do you mean the joint distribution? What other information do you have? Obviously not every two normal random variables are independent, or even jointly normal. I hope you will type out your question clearly, and someone will likely answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine throwing a fair, six-sided die. We model the possible outcomes and their probabilities using a probability space, where  $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\mathcal p$ is the power set of $\Omega$, and $P(A):=\frac{\#A}{6}$, where $\#A$ is the number of elements of $A$ (so it's a uniform probability distribution). This is our underlying probability space.

Once we have this probability space (and not a second earlier!) we can define random variables on it. This underlying space is crucial, since random variables are functions with this probability space as their domain. For instance, we could define the random variable $X$ which measures wether the roll yields an even number, so $X(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in\Omega$ is even, and $X(\omega)=0$ otherwise. Similarly, we could define a completely different random variable $Y$ on the same probability space, measuring wether the roll yields a prime. These two random variables are not independent, since the chance that the roll yields an even prime is $1/6$ (since 2 is the only even prime), but if they were independent it would be $P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)=\frac12 \cdot\frac12=\frac14$.

Usually when working on modeling any problem in probability, you will be working with one single underlying probability space on which all necessary random variables are defined. Often this space won't be mentioned explicitly. It's just a given that it's there. It's also not important how exactly it looks. The only thing that's important is how the random variables we define on it are distributed (that's the probability distribution you mentioned, which *does* depend on the random variable) and how they interact. But we can take two completely different probability spaces and define sets of random variables on both such that their distributions and interactions are exactly the same, so it really doesn't matter how the probability space looks. The only thing it has to do is *be there*. But we rarely have to actually work with it, since it's not our object if interest - the random variables are.

Comment: But how would find the probability of the intersection part? If X and Y are RV, then P(X$ \in A$ and Y $\in B$)=P($X \in A$). P(Y  $\in B$), but how do we find P for the intersection part when $\Omega$ and P are not known? The other two Probabilities will definitely come from distributions.

Comment: Your equation is only true for independent random variables, not for random variables in general. Anyway, if you want to calculate such probabilities, you need additional information, otherwise it's just not possible. How you can't calculate it depends on the information you have, and can't really be condensed in one answer or comment. Maybe you know that they are perfectly correlated. Or you know that they are components of a known multivariate normal distribution. Or you know certain conditional probabilities which allow you to find the joint distribution. It really depends.

Comment: you are right. This is what I was wondering.